# Error: incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef, incomplete-type

in **.h**:

```
typedef struct token_t TOKEN;
```

in **.c**:

```
#include "token.h"

struct token_t
{
    char* start;
    int length;
    int type;
};
```

in **main.c**:

```
#include "token.h"

int main ()
{
    TOKEN* tokens; // here: ok
    TOKEN token;   // here: Error: incomplete type is not allowed
    // ...
}
```

The error I get in that last line:

> Error: incomplete type is not allowed

What's wrong?

Comment: post the arguments with which you are compiling

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to move the definition of the `struct` into the header file:

```
/* token.h */

struct token_t
{
    char* start;
    int length;
    int type;
};
```

Comment: @Fabricio: you can hide it if you use opaque pointers, as you have seen.

Comment: It needs to be visible at the point where you create an instance of the struct. Otherwise the compiler has no way of knowing its size, its fields etc.

Answer (score 9):

In main module there is no definition of the structure. You have to include it in the header, The compiler does not know how much memory to allocate for this definition

```
TOKEN token;
```

because the size of the structure is unknown. A type with unknown size is an incomplete type.

For example you could write in the header

```
typedef struct token_t
{
    char* start;
    int length;
    int type;
} TOKEN;
```